# Multiple static classes with the same name

Tags: java, namespaces, inner-classes

I'm writing a compiler that targets Java 8 code. The source language permits C++-like namespaces that may be nested; the target must reflect this. For example:

```
// all members removed
class Arctan {
  public static class Arctan {     // error: Duplicate class 'Arctan'
     public static class a {
        public static class b {
        }
     }

     public static class c {
        public static class a {
           public static class b {
           }

           public static class c {        // error: Duplicate class 'c'
              public static class a {     // error: Duplicate class 'a'
                 public static class b {
                 }

              }

           }

        }
     }

     public static class m {
        public static class b {
        }
     }
  }
}
```

However, this yields a `class Arctan is already defined in package unnamed package public static class Arctan` error. One colleague has suggested making each `static class` a singleton instead; while this is a good idea, I am concerned it may complicate some of the generated code, or it may make the implementation messy.

The choice of `static class`  is in the absence of a C++ `namespace` equivalent, and the generated code must all be in the same file (this is part of the design spec).

I'm wondering if there's an alternative to using a singleton.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: What's wrong with giving them different names? Or just putting them in different class files, but related through the same package?

Comment: Added query to original post, sorry!

Comment: can you show the exact error message?

Comment: @Gavriel Doubt it's an error, just a compilation message thrown by the IDE

Comment: @Zizouz212, still, I would be happy to see the exact error or message, no matter how it's called. You know, it might have some information in it...

Comment: @Gavriel

`class Arctan is already defined in package unnamed package
   public static class Arctan`

Same issue when it is in a package.

Comment: And the code? remove all members, leave just the package and all the nested classes. OR try it with the code you posted

Comment: Added to original post for readability.

Comment: I've also marked where the errors occur in the code.

Comment: I think you are complicating the error.  The issue is simply: a nested class cannot be named the same as any of its outer classes

Comment: Should I implement a name-mangling solution then? e.g. Arctan -> Arctan0, Arctan1, etc.

Comment: @cjdb, if you can, then try it, it sounds like a good idea